# Database missing error

Tags: mysql, xampp, database-backups

In my xampp,i could not start the MYSQL section.So XAMP re installed.Before reinstallation i keep database backup from the path `C:\xampp\mysql\data`.
After reinstallation paste datafolder content into this path.Then I tried to accessing `phpmyadmin`,then database and table names are listed there.But there is no content into each table.While clicking the database table, it shows an error `table does not exist`.Please give any solution for my this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't back it up with copy-paste of files. You need to use a tool like `mysqldump` or the MySQL Workbench tool to do that for you properly.

Comment: Agreed to @tadman. Use a tool or cmd to backup your DB.

Comment: please help me ....give any clue to use cmd to backup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, dumping DBs is pretty easy. I assume you are on `localhost` and your user name is `root`.

1. Make sure your MySQL server is up and running.
2. Run Command line and for dumping ALL your DBs, type:

`mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > dump.sql`

Hit Enter. The system will ask you for a MySQL password, type it and hit enter. If there's no password set for your server, just hit Enter. Your dump file will be saved in the current directory.

3. To restore the dump (e.g. after you reinstalled MySQL), run Command line again and make sure you are in the same directory where your dump.sql is. Type:

`mysql -u root -p < dump.sql`

It will ask you for a password. You know what to do. Depending on how many data you have it can take some prolonged time. Hope it will help!

P.S. Dumping/restoring single DB is a little bit different, let me know if you need it and I will update this post.